# Find results duplicated

Tags: bash

I have a script that looks for files on a mass filer device. Every day, it searches about 250,000 files and creates a simple report that counts how many files we received, broken down by sender (`$1`) and by date (`$11`).

For efficiency purpose, I use the `‑exec` with a plus-sign in my find() expression to grab filenames into groups.

```
find . -exec ls '{}' +| awk -F~ '{print $1"\t"$11}'|sort|uniq -c
```

It works fast but duplicates results like so

```
  9632 ./Reynosa    20120607
   9632 Reynosa 20120607
  20328 ./Reynosa   20120608
  20328 Reynosa 20120608
  15354 ./Reynosa   20120609
  15354 Reynosa 20120609
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use  `basename` to strip out the `./` or is there a better way?

Comment: Please show an example output from the `find` portion of the pipeline alone. Why won't `-print` do what you want instead of `-exec ls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ls -d` instead of `ls`. From the manpage:

```
-d, --directory
          list directory entries instead of contents, and do not  dereference symbolic links
```

Your current command lists the entries of the directories as well, which are then listed again by find, thus resulting in duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using `ls -d` got me what I wanted. Accepted and voted up.

Answer (score 0):

you should use -type f in find as in

```
 find . -type f -exec ....
```